# Index out of range data nil swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofireimage

I have data coming from Json and populating it inside an UIImage using alamofireImage. One of those elements that I am getting back from Json is a String that has a URL to an image. If a particular Json string is null or blank I get the following error :

> fatal error: Index out of range

```
EventEngine.getEventGalery(invitedID, limit: "2") { (result, error) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

        if let response = result as? EventGaleryResponse{

            self.galery = response.data!

            let jsonDict = self.galery
            print("jsonDict \(jsonDict![0].photo!)")
            if jsonDict![0].photo != nil {
                self.imagearry1.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: jsonDict![0].photo!)!)
            }
            if jsonDict![1].photo != nil {
                self.imagearry2.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string:jsonDict![1].photo!)!)
            }
            if jsonDict![2].photo != nil {
                self.imagearry3.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: jsonDict![2].photo!)!)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You are getting the first element of jsonDict, using "jsonDict[0]", but you did not check if it is empty. jsonDict can be not null and also be empty.

Comment: `jsonDict![0]` That's so irritating to name a var Dict, when it seems to be in fact an array. And since it's an array, `jsonDict![2]` could causes a crash because you don't check if it has at least 3 elements... (and so on for the others).

Comment: thaks for answere. how to i checkif it is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please never use `!` operator without checks. I really suggest to use `if let` construction instead.

Some pseudocode (I dont know your types) :

```
EventEngine.getEventGalery(invitedID, limit: "2") { (result, error) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

        if let response = result as? EventGaleryResponse{

            self.galery = response.data!

            let jsonDict = self.galery

            if let dict = jsonDict {
                setPhotoFromDict(dict, 0, self.imagearry1)
                setPhotoFromDict(dict, 1, self.imagearry2)
                setPhotoFromDict(dict, 2, self.imagearry3)
            } else {
                print("cannot deserialise \(String(describing: jsonDict)")
            }
        }
    })
}

private func setPhotoFromDict(<#DictType#> dict, Int index, <#ImageArrayType#> imageArary) {
    if let photo = dict[index].photo as? String, let url = URL(string: photo) {
        imageArary.af_setImage(withURL: url)
    }
}
```

And the initial error comes from  this line `print("jsonDict \(jsonDict![0].photo!)")`, I guess, because you access object without check

Comment: hi anton, what do you mean by DictType and ImageArrayType?

Comment: The types of jsonDict and imagearry respectively.

Answer (score 2):

**I think,  you did not check if it is empty**

```
EventEngine.getEventGalery(invitedID, limit: "2") { (result, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                if let response = result as? EventGaleryResponse{

                    self.galery = response.data!

                    let jsonDict = self.galery

                   if jsonDict != nil {

                    if jsonDict.count > 0 && jsonDict![0].photo != nil {
                        self.imagearry1.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: jsonDict![0].photo!)!)
                    }
                    if jsonDict.count > 1 && jsonDict![1].photo != nil {
                        self.imagearry2.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string:jsonDict![1].photo!)!)
                    }
                    if jsonDict.count > 2 && jsonDict![2].photo != nil {
                        self.imagearry3.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: jsonDict![2].photo!)!)
                    }

                  }
                }
            })
        }
```